# htmlspecialchars "Forbidden code point" validation error

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding, w3c-validation

My php script is getting rows from a MySQL table that contain strings such as the following:

```
$string = 'ï¼’ã¤ã®ä¹³é…¸èŒã®ç¨';
```

Is there a way to echo these sorts of strings to the browser without getting "Forbidden code point" when running the document through an HTML5 validator?

I have tried the following:

```
htmlspecialchars($string);
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8');
htmlspecialchars(mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8');
```

but all of these expressions still result in the "Forbidden code point" error. The encoding of the webpage is already set to UTF-8 via a meta tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED);
```

This converted as many characters as possible to UTF-8 and removed everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function `htmlentities()` may be what you are looking for.
This function will convert applicable characters supplied into it to HTML entities.

For example:

`$string = 'ï¼’ã¤ã®ä¹³é…¸èŒã®ç¨';
$string = htmlentities($string);
echo $string;`

Will convert your string of `ï¼’ã¤ã®ä¹³é…¸èŒã®ç¨` into `&iuml;&frac14;&rsquo;&atilde;&curren;&atilde;&reg;&auml;&sup1;&sup3;&eacute;&hellip;&cedil;&egrave;&OElig;&atilde;&reg;&ccedil;&uml;uml;` which can be used to display on an HTML page without error.

More information on this function an be found here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Thank you. However, I still ended up with invalid characters.